# Match.index not work correctly

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to find `[Key]` word in my text and add something to it.

```
class Program
{
    private string x = "public class Table \n{\n[Key]\r\n[MaxLength(36)]\r\npublic string Char366{ get; set; }\npublic short? Blooean{ get; set; }\n[Key]\r\npublic bool Bit1{ get; set; }\npublic byte? Tinyinttunsigned{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Binaryy{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Varbinaryy{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Blobb{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Longblobb{ get; set; }\npublic DateTime Datetimee{ get; set; }\npublic decimal Decimall{ get; set; }\npublic double Doublee{ get; set; }\npublic short? Smallintt{ get; set; }\npublic int? Intt{ get; set; }\npublic long Bigintt{ get; set; }\npublic short Tinyintt{ get; set; }\n[Key]\r\npublic float Floatt{ get; set; }\n[MaxLength(1)]\r\npublic string Charr{ get; set; }\n[MaxLength(100)]\r\npublic string Varcharr{ get; set; }\npublic string Textt{ get; set; }\npublic string Longtextt{ get; set; }\npublic TimeSpan Timee{ get; set; }\npublic int? Mediumintt{ get; set; }\npublic long Biggintt{ get; set; }\npublic DateTime Datee{ get; set; }\npublic DateTime Timestampp{ get; set; }\npublic short Yearr{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Tinyblobb{ get; set; }\npublic string Tinytextt{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Mediumblobb{ get; set; }\npublic string Mediumtextt{ get; set; }\npublic string Longtexttm{ get; set; }\n[MaxLength(7)]\r\npublic string Enumm{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Geometryyycol{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Geometryyy{ get; set; }\n}";



    private void method()
    {
        var wordToFind = @"\[(Key)\]";
        var occurrences = Regex.Matches(x,wordToFind);
        var timesOfOccurrences = 0;


            foreach (Match m in occurrences)
            {
                timesOfOccurrences++;
                x = x.Insert(m.Index + m.Length-1, string.Format(",Order={0}", timesOfOccurrences));
            }

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It works fine only with the first occurrence of the word. Is there something wrong with my regex? Here is result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you did not take into account that the input string is changed after the first iteration. The indices you collected with `Regex.Matches` have been shifted after you replaced the first `[Key]` with `[Key,Order=1]` 8 characters.

I suggest using a `Regex.Replace` with a  match evaluator  to do the replacing. It will be much cleaner and less error prone:

```
string x = "public class Table \n{\n[Key]\r\n[MaxLength(36)]\r\npublic string Char366{ get; set; }\npublic short? Blooean{ get; set; }\n[Key]\r\npublic bool Bit1{ get; set; }\npublic byte? Tinyinttunsigned{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Binaryy{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Varbinaryy{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Blobb{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Longblobb{ get; set; }\npublic DateTime Datetimee{ get; set; }\npublic decimal Decimall{ get; set; }\npublic double Doublee{ get; set; }\npublic short? Smallintt{ get; set; }\npublic int? Intt{ get; set; }\npublic long Bigintt{ get; set; }\npublic short Tinyintt{ get; set; }\n[Key]\r\npublic float Floatt{ get; set; }\n[MaxLength(1)]\r\npublic string Charr{ get; set; }\n[MaxLength(100)]\r\npublic string Varcharr{ get; set; }\npublic string Textt{ get; set; }\npublic string Longtextt{ get; set; }\npublic TimeSpan Timee{ get; set; }\npublic int? Mediumintt{ get; set; }\npublic long Biggintt{ get; set; }\npublic DateTime Datee{ get; set; }\npublic DateTime Timestampp{ get; set; }\npublic short Yearr{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Tinyblobb{ get; set; }\npublic string Tinytextt{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Mediumblobb{ get; set; }\npublic string Mediumtextt{ get; set; }\npublic string Longtexttm{ get; set; }\n[MaxLength(7)]\r\npublic string Enumm{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Geometryyycol{ get; set; }\npublic byte[] Geometryyy{ get; set; }\n}";
var wordToFind = @"\[(Key)\]";
var occurrences = Regex.Matches(x, wordToFind);
var timesOfOccurrences = 0;
var result = Regex.Replace(x, wordToFind, m => string.Format("[{0},Order={1}]", m.Groups[1].Value, ++timesOfOccurrences));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ELOH4J)

Note that `timesOfOccurrences` is incremented inside the match evaluator.

Comment: I also provided the reason why the code failed at the beginning. Since you are modifying the input string, all the indices shift. That is why performing the replacement inside a match evaluator is safer.